# webcam usage in opencv

Tags: opencv, webcam

I am new with opencv.
I want to capture images from webcam (intex it-105wc).
I am using Microsoft visual c++ 2008 express edition on windows xp.
There is no problem with build solution, but when i try to debug the code it gives following (this happens wwhile executing cvCaptureFromCAM(CV_CAP_ANY);)

Loaded `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Ahead\DSFilter\NeVideo.ax`, Binary was not built with debug information.

and then exits the code.

so, is there any problem with my code or is it compatibility issue with webcam??

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<stdio.h>
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>

void main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    int c;
    IplImage* color_img;
    CvCapture* cv_cap = cvCaptureFromCAM(CV_CAP_ANY);

    if(!cv_cap)
        {
            printf( "ERROR: Capture is null!\n");
        }

    cvNamedWindow("Video",0); // create window

    for(;;) 
            {
        color_img = cvQueryFrame(cv_cap); // get frame

        if(color_img != 0)
            cvShowImage("Video", color_img); // show frame

        c = cvWaitKey(10); // wait 10 ms or for key stroke

        if(c == 27)
            break; // if ESC, break and quit
    }

    /* clean up */
    cvReleaseCapture( &cv_cap );
    cvDestroyWindow("Video");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message seems to be related to a video codec from the nero burning tools.
If you do not need this codec, you could just unregister it and see, if that solves your problem.

To do that, execute the following on the commandline:

```
regsvr32 /u "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Ahead\DSFilter\NeVideo.ax"
```

You should see the message:

```
DllUnregisterServer in C:\Program Files\Common Files\Ahead\DSFilter\NeVideo.ax succeeded.
```

To undo this, execute

```
regsvr32 "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Ahead\DSFilter\NeVideo.ax"
```